# Removing pandas rows that columns don't match with the same values but include empty columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have these two pandas dfs and I know how to remove the rows that columns don't match with the same values, but I also want to keep the rows where one of the columns are empty (I don't want those to be removed).

```
   V1                 V2          V3
hello                 0            0
nice                  0            1
meeting               1            1
you                   1            0
hi                    0
```

```
   V1                 V2          V3
hello                 0            0
meeting               1            1
hi                    0
```

What I've tried:

```
df = df[df.V2 == df.V3]
```

Problem: it removes the rows with one empty column

Comment: Does using`df[(df.V2 == df.V3) | (df.V3.isnull()) | (df.V2.isnull())]` give the expected result?

Comment: Another option `df.loc[np.where((df['V2'] == df['V3']) | (df['V3'].isna()))]` This will use numpy as an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some good answers in the comments, here's another alternative:

```
df[df.V3.fillna(df.V2).eq(df.V2)]
```